# Display all rows with different ID and calculate their realization time

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, average

I didnt find appropriate answer to my question (i really apologize if i overlooked it), so i create a new one.

In my program i enter the product ID (in this case it is "IZ09273") and i get a DataGridView like this (im working in VB.net). The table contains product, all workers ID that are working on this product and their realization time. If we look at worker ID "152", this is the same person who is manufacturing the same product but with different realization time.

```
Product  WorkerID    RealizationTime
IZ09273     152     23.5.2014 12:08:23
IZ09273     152     23.5.2014 12:13:41
IZ09273     152     23.5.2014 12:18:26
IZ09273     152     23.5.2014 12:23:11
IZ09273     152     23.5.2014 12:27:22
IZ09273     152     23.5.2014 12:32:27
IZ09273     152     23.5.2014 12:36:22
IZ09273     243     27.2.2013 10:58:10
IZ09273     243     27.2.2013 11:04:49
IZ09273     243     27.2.2013 11:09:58
IZ09273     243     27.2.2013 12:57:41
IZ09273     243     27.2.2013 13:01:23
IZ09273     243     27.2.2013 13:05:14
IZ09273     243     27.2.2013 13:08:40
IZ09273     336     28.5.2013 16:22:27
IZ09273     419     1.10.2013 18:03:15
IZ09273     419     1.10.2013 18:12:22
IZ09273     419     1.10.2013 18:16:55
IZ09273     419     1.10.2013 18:25:19
IZ09273     419     1.10.2013 21:15:53
IZ09273     419     1.10.2013 21:24:08
IZ09273     419     1.10.2013 21:28:25
IZ09273     419     25.9.2014 14:45:48
IZ09273     528     27.2.2013 16:12:19
IZ09273     528     27.2.2013 16:18:19
IZ09273     528     27.2.2013 16:22:36
```

I would like to get all workers ID for product "IZ09273" and then calculate their AVG, MIN and MAX realization time - in seconds (i dont need date, just time and it must be in seconds)

The result should be like this:

```
WorkerID     AVG    MIN    MAX
152          ...    ...    ...
243          ...    ...    ...
336
419
528
```

I hope it is understandable enough.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Can you explain how to find min, max and Avg for one workerid ( ex:152)

Comment: How do you calculate "realization time in seconds", `RealizationTime` is a timestamp? Do you mean the difference between the timestamps of two consecutive rows?

Comment: @Steve I am using MS SQL

Comment: @NoDisplayName Thats what i would like to know too...

Comment: @dnoeth My bad... yes, i need a difference between the timestamps of two consecutive rows. I need that for every WorkerID and from there on i guess i can get avg, min and max for every workerID? But i dont know exactly how to do it?

Comment: i didn't ask you write sql query.. manually explain how to calculate

Answer (score 0):

Since SQL Server 2012 there's the LAG/LEAD functions to get the previous/next rows value:

```
select WorkerID
  ,min(diff)
  ,avg(diff)
  ,max(diff)
from
 (
   select WorkerID
      ,datediff(second
               ,lag(RealizationTime) 
                over (partition by WorkerID
                      order by RealizationTime)
               ,RealizationTime
               ) as diff
   from tab
 ) as dt
group by WorkerID
```

You might need to add some condition to filter for data like the last two rows from WorkerID 419 like `case when diff > 10000 the null else diff end`

Edit:
Before SQL Server 2012 the LAG/LEAD can be calculated using a Scalar Subquery.

```
select WorkerID
  ,min(diff)
  ,avg(diff)
  ,max(diff)
from
 (
   select WorkerID
      ,datediff(second
               ,(select max(RealizationTime) 
                  from tab as t2
                  where t1.WorkerID = t2.WorkerID
                    and t2.RealizationTime < t1.RealizationTime)
/*               ,lag(RealizationTime) 
                over (partition by WorkerID
                      order by RealizationTime)
*/               ,RealizationTime
               ) as diff
   from tab as t1
 ) as dt
group by WorkerID
```

Comment: Sorry for not replying for so long, i was away... Well when i try your solution, i get an "'lag' is not a recognized built-in function name" error. Maybe because i work with MS SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: SS2008 doesn't support LAG, yet, but you can rewrite it using a Scalar Subquery, edited my answer

Comment: When i put your code in SQL i get the folloeing error --> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation. 

When i put the code in Visual Studio, i get this --> Incorrect syntax near ')'.
"t1" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90.

I really dont know what is the matter here... if you can help mel

Comment: I created a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0daf3/1/0 which works fine. Don't know why it fails in Studio, but the overflow error might be due to the actual datatypes...

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is order all your data for a given Product ID by WorkerID and by RealisationTime and index each row accordingly. Notice the Index restarts when the worker ID changes (and the productID if you were querying on more than one processed)

```
Product  WorkerID    RealizationTime        Index
IZ09273     152     23.5.2014 12:08:23      1
IZ09273     152     23.5.2014 12:13:41      2
IZ09273     152     23.5.2014 12:18:26      3
IZ09273     152     23.5.2014 12:23:11      4
IZ09273     152     23.5.2014 12:27:22      5
IZ09273     152     23.5.2014 12:32:27      6
IZ09273     152     23.5.2014 12:36:22      7
IZ09273     243     27.2.2013 10:58:10      1
IZ09273     243     27.2.2013 11:04:49      2
```

The row_number function in sql is perfect for this as you can get it to start the index again by making use of Partition. Having done this you can now link each row to its successive row by joining on Index + 1 = Index. Which means you can get the difference between the realisation times.

See sql below as this demonstrates how it works

```
select WorkerID, RealisationTime, Row_Number() over(Partition By ProductID, WorkerID order by RealisationTime) as rn into #Times
From Data

select A.WorkerID, Avg(DateDiff(Second, A.RealisationTime, B.RealisationTime)) as AvgT,
Min(DateDiff(Second, A.RealisationTime, B.RealisationTime)) as MinT,
Max(DateDiff(Second, A.RealisationTime, B.RealisationTime)) as AvgT
from #Times A
inner join #Times B on A.ProductId = B.ProductId and A.WorkerID = B.WorkerID and A.RN + 1 = B.RN
Where A.ProductId = 'IZ09273'
group By A.WorkerID
```

Comment: I undertand your answer, i just don't know what the ProcessID is and where did you get it? Thank you

Comment: Sorry typo should have been procduct ID